# Is there a way to pre-cache a web page for viewing with an Android WebView?

Tags: java, android, html, caching, webview

I've read about the HTML5 cache manifest, and I've seen Android does support caching websites using the cache manifest. I want to use the cache manifest to download all the required resources for my website to preload it, and then open a WebView and display the remote website using the pre-cached resources. I want to pre-cache my remote page somehow, preferably without using a WebView for the caching process.

The problem with using a WebView for the pre-caching process is that loading the webpage using a WebView renders and executes the page instead of just downloading it.

I've read this: http://alex.tapmania.org/2010/11/html5-cache-android-webview.html, but having a WebView support caching is not what I want. I want the loading process to be instantaneous (assuming the cache manifest / etags of the remote website are the same as the cached version) right after I finish pre-caching the resources, instead of waiting for the WebView to load up and cache everything on the first access.

What is the correct way of pre-caching web pages for viewing later?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want to do requires implementing a mechanism for app cache, linked resources, cookies, and local database store for HTML5 apps that use database API, and that's an important part of what browsers do in these days. I don't recommend doing the caching by yourself, not only because it's so much work, but also because I can't recall any method in `WebView` and it's friends (`WebViewClient`, etc.) that accepts an outside cache.

But your problem has a very simpler solution: you can put a `WebView` in your view and set its `visibility` to `gone`. Then make it visible when it has finished loading the page. `WebView` also automatically keeps the cache for your app so that the next time it runs it loads the page more quickly.

For hiding your `WebView` and then automatically showing it you just have to override `onPageFinished` in [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html).