# Can I wake up the phone and run an activity without lighting up the screen?

Tags: android, android-activity

If I use a BroadcastReceiver to trigger an activity and wake up the phone, can the activity fulfill its job without lighting up the screen? I cannot use a service because in my app there are some features only supported in activities.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. An activity is either paused or stopped which means it cannot run anything. What features do you want to use? Perhaps it is possibe another way.

Comment: It is Android webview...I want to cache some webpages for later use, but webview can only be deployed in an activity.

Comment: This article may be the only way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626566/is-there-a-way-to-pre-cache-a-web-page-for-viewing-with-an-android-webview